# How to test a function passed as props to child in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I need some advice on how to write tests for React component. I have 2 approaches in my mind, feel free to suggest more.

I have a component `App` which renders a `ComplexSearchBox`. I pass this `ComplexSearchBox` a prop `onSearch`, the value of this prop is a function. This function is invoked by `ComplexSearchBox` at various user interactions like when the user hits enter on the input box or clicks the search button.

```
const App = () => {
    return <ComplexSearchBox onSearch={query => console.log(query)}/>;
};
```

I want to write tests for `App` component. I'm using Enzyme to write tests.
I'm following some principles of React Testing Library.
I'm mounting the component. So this will render all children as well. I don't want to render `ComplexSearchBox` so I'll mock it.

This is where my problem is. I have 2 approaches in my mind.

1. I can get the props of `ComplexSearchBox` and invoke the method directly with the required parameters.

```
jest.mock('Path To ComplexSearchBox', function ComplexSearchBox() {
    return null;
});

describe('App', () => {
    describe('when search button is clicked', () => {
        it('should log to console by invoking prop method', () => {
            const wrapper = mount(<App/>);
            wrapper.find('ComplexSearchBox').props().onSearch('My random test query');
            //expect something
        });
    });
});
```

2. I can mock the `ComplexSearchBox` and return a simplified version of it. Now I can type the query in an input box and then click a button to submit.

```
jest.mock('Path To ComplexSearchBox', function ComplexSearchBox({onSearch}) {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('Sample Search Query');
    return <div>
        <input value={query} onChange={setQuery}/>
        <button onClick={() => onSearch(query)}/>
    </div>;
});

describe('App', () => {
    describe('when search button is clicked', () => {
        it('should log to console by clicking', () => {
            const wrapper = mount(<App/>);
            wrapper.find('input').simulate('change', {target: {value: 'My random test query'}});
            wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
            //expect something
        });
    });
});
```

I see value in the second approach. However, I'm not sure if it is worth the effort of creating a simplified version every time I have to interact with a child component.

The benefit of the second approach is that

1. It decouples the code from tests. My tests don't have to know which method to invoke with what parameter when the user wants to execute a search. Mock knows which method to invoke but that is at one place and not spread across all the tests.
2. I find tests to be more readable and behaviour oriented when written this way.
3. This mock can be extracted out and used at multiple places. Making writing tests easier.
4. Any method sequencing can be abstracted in the mock component. Like if I modify the `ComplexSearchBox` as below.

```
const App = () => {
    return <ComplexSearchBox preProcess={()=>{}} onSearch={query => console.log(query)} postProcess={()=>{}}/>;
};

jest.mock('Path To ComplexSearchBox', function ComplexSearchBox({preProcess, onSearch, postProcess}) {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('Sample Search Query');
    const search = (query) => {
        const preProcessedQuery = preProcess(query);
        const searchedQuery = onSearch(preProcessedQuery);
        postProcess(searchedQuery);
    };
    return <div>
        <input value={query} onChange={setQuery}/>
        <button onClick={() => search(query)}/>
    </div>;
});
```

Though I'm not very sure if the last benefit is really a benefit. As now my mock is aware of the lifecycle of `ComplexSearchBox`. But on the other hand, this mock will be written only once and will save me from calling those 3 methods one after the other in a lot of tests.
I could also argue that a component test written with approach one should not really care about the method sequencing as that is `ComplexSearchBox` responsibility.
Those 3 methods do have a tight coupling as one's output is next one's input. And now I'm borderline integration testing these 2 components.

I could also have 3 buttons which have `onClick` to run those 3 methods and now I can test them individually.

I'm not really sure which approach is better. I'm leaning a bit towards approach 2 because it makes my tests less dependent on implementation.

I'd appreciate any advice on this and if you have another way to test this scenario then please share.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact answer for you, but I highly suggest reading this article:

https://kentcdodds.com/blog/why-i-never-use-shallow-rendering

In it, you will find arguments against shallow rendering, and in favour or integration tests in React.

The points you made are all valid, if you choose the route of unit testing, therefore mocking all subcomponents of the `<App />` component, you will be coupling your tests to the current implementation of those subcomponents, and anytime you change those subcomponents, even if the refactor doesn't change the behaviour, you run the risk of breaking the `<App />`s test.

I don't believe there is a way around it when you are dealing with mocks, so I would suggest considering the article above and not mocking anything, which might run the tests a little slower, but it probably won't be a big deal most of the time!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After reading Kent’s blog couple of years back, I adopted some principles of RTL.
I stopped using "setState" and invoking methods using "instance". Tests shouldn’t know the implementation. I started using “mount” instead of “shallow”.
However, I disagree with not mocking anything. Testing high-level container components becomes a challenge, one ends up with brittle tests.
Kent mentions how he mocks third-party library. I use the same way to mock children component. My issue comes when I pass a function as a prop. Do I invoke a prop or make mocked child invoke prop.

Comment: Generally when I mock components I make assertions that they were invoked with the correct props (in your case the function), and I mock the result of all necessary behaviour for the test I need. So i would not invoke the funcion passed as prop, I would only assert the component had received it correctly, and assume that the behaviour happens correctly inside the subcomponent.

Comment: If you don't invoke the passed function then how do you test the function being passed? I could change the logic inside that function and no unit test would break.

Comment: Yes it is a valid concern, but I would suggest another solution for that. You keep mocking the execution/return of subcomponent, and you extract the function you want to test to a helper file, where you can unit test the function in isolation.

Comment: Your approach of "extraction" is a valid solution. However, it may not be always feasible.

Usually, the function passed to a child is like "setState" or "() => dispatch(someAction())".
It involves passing something related to react/redux, like "setState", or "dispatch" or something. Extracting that to a helper function might be a bit too complicated.

If I'm passing such a function then I'd prefer invoking the function by using any of the two approaches that I mentioned.